# Upload excel file with the same related ids from other tables

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel

I want to upload an excel file to my database, but my database tables have this structure

Model

```
$table->id();
    $table->string('orderNumb');
    $table->integer('customer_id');
    $table->string('loading_point');
    $table->date('looade_date');
    $table->string('border_name');
    $table->integer('team_id');
    $table->string('truck_number');
    $table->string('trailer_number');
    $table->integer('master_qty');
    $table->integer('slave_qty');
```

How can i insert `team_id`,`border_id` because a user can not know this `ids` because this ids are related from another table,

what can i do a user can fill the name as well and import the excel without mixed the data.

Comment: Create a team and later user and associate team later !?

Comment: @AnanthSathvick i have already the created the team and user

Comment: Then you can assign a team to user something like this `$user ->team()->associate($team)` where $user is the user model and $team is the team model

Comment: where i can add this ?